# Unable to change system time in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datetime

I was unable to change my system time( without using any UI) on my android app.

The idea is:

1. Retrieve current system time
2. Switch current time forward and backward for a few hours( without using any UI)
   Note that the android app will be run in a root device.

Below is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_open = findViewById(R.id.btn_startxk);
        btn_open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SimpleDateFormat simpdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                String cur_time = simpdate.format(cal.getTime());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, cur_time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TimeManager timeManager = TimeManager.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
                long timeStamp = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                timeManager.setTime(timeStamp);

    }
```

Could anyone help to correct my code?

Comment: TimeManager is for Android Things devices which dont really exist anymore and will not work on normal devices, you cant set the system time from your app. You need to have a rooted device

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Infact im using an emulator and already enable root access.